# uunable to pass current activity from asynctask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to pass current activity object to custom listview adapter but am getting nullpointer exception as it is being passed from async class. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names

 static final String Events_date = "ev_date";
 static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
 static final String TAG_ID = "id";
 static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
 static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
 static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();        
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
     }
```

and here is adapterclass main code snippets

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
// public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater =     (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
 //   imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
  }
```

I understand that I am supposed to pass instance of MainActivity. So,can any one tell me how to do it, as if I am calling a function from postexecute then also getting  nullpointer as data is not being inserted in hashmap.Kindly help!!!

Log cat:

```
01-25 23:08:29.779: D/Response:(607):                 "name": "Clint Eastwood",
01-25 23:08:29.779: D/Response:(607):                 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - coun
01-25 23:08:30.029: D/AndroidRuntime(607): Shutting down VM
01-25 23:08:30.029: W/dalvikvm(607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-25 23:08:30.052: E/AndroidRuntime(607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 23:08:30.052: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.MainActivity$GetContacts.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:155)
01-25 23:08:30.052: E/AndroidRuntime(607):  at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.MainActivity$GetContacts.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MainActivity.this` to refer to the parent class `this` in a nested class such as your async task.

However, this requires that you keep your asynctask nested class non-static which isn't a good idea. Non-static nested class hold references to their parent (activity in this case) and since activity and asynctask lifecycles are different, the asynctask can hold onto the wrong activity for too long.

Answer (score 0):

use    `adapter=new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);`

only `this` will pass the asynctask class context.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new constructor for the AsyncTask accepting an Activity as input parameter

```
public GetContacts(Activity mActivity){
this.mActivity = mActivity;}
```

In the doInBackground method you could then use mActivity but be aware that until you have a reference to the Activity, this one cannot die.

When creating the AsyncTask from the MainActivity, you could just pass this as input parameter and it should work.